# I cannot create vue project with npm

Tags: npm, vuejs3

When I try to create a new vue project with `npm create vue@latest` in my cmd, I get this error:

`npm ERR! code 1`

`npm ERR! path C:\Users\SEMİH`

`npm ERR! command failed`

`npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c create-vue`

`npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\SEMİH\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-25T20_13_54_384Z-debug-0.log`

I tried to delete nodejs and reinstall but it did not work. I tried to globally download vue-cli. I added path variable as C:\Users\SEMİH\AppData\Roaming\npm

Comment: What does the log in `C:\Users\SEMİH\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-25T20_13_54_384Z-debug-0.log` show?

Comment: @ceejayoz this is the log https://pastebin.com/UXTNvMHB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happened because of the "İ" character in C:\Users\SEMİH. When I changed the folder name to something else it worked